# Stream audio with RTP without using Websocket

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming, rtp

I am working on a softphone solution with electron js, I already implemented my own SIP/SDP over UDP (using dgram), now for RTP/RTCP to send audio, I found rtp-session nodejs module and documentation about getUserMedia(). The softphone will connect to Asterisk through UDP only, no encryption, no websocket, and the RTP audio channel is going through Asterisk, no direct-connect between softphones. My Question is how to send audio stream through an RTP session? Can somebody show me a piece of code of how to handle Mediastream and send it through RTP, this is the class I get from rtp-session:

https://github.com/MayamaTakeshi/rtp-session/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Do you need to do this over http?

Comment: No, pure over UDP, no http involved, I am using dgram to create UDP socket.

Comment: the rtp-session module has the class: RtpSession that has this method: send_payload(payload, marker_bit, payload_type).

Comment: Hi, @Yoandy, did you find any solution?